# VS 2012 publish setting with different profiles

Tags: asp.net, deployment, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to find a way to simplify our deployment process

We are developing under ASP.NET 4.5 platform and
currently we have 3 environments DEV/TEST/PROD and for each of the environment we have different configurations , that we are manually changing after copying published files to the Server.
(now all .config files are excluded during Xcopy process)

I am looking for the way to manage all configurations in VS 2012 , and according to publish profile , I'd like VS will wire up right .config files during publish.

Is there any good article that explains how to do this ?

Any link to the tutorial will be helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: Read about config Transformation, Release and Debug config setting

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for , convert your comment to answer